# Redirect after Login on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a customized WordPress theme based on an existing site.

I want to use an alternate dashboard which I have created.

How can I have the user directed to '`news.php`' after login instead of '`/wp-admin/`' ?

--

EDIT: *Have a working Plug-in for this but the bounty is still availible for anyone who can find a manual way to do this through functions.php, as it would be more secure then using a 3rd party plug-in.*

Comment: Where is `news.php` - in the front end or within the administration area (i.e. dashboard, i.e. a child of `/wp-admin/...`)? Could you supply a full path? `example.com/...` and then what?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

This should solve your problem. Adapted from an answer found [here.](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-filter-login_redirect)

Add the following snippet of code in the functions.php file of your theme:

```
function admin_default_page() {
  return '/new-dashboard-url';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

Comment: Unfortunately my functions.php file doesn't contain anything similar to the person who had posted on that site.

Comment: This works for me! The functions.php file doesn't have to contain anything like this, just add this code to the file!

Comment: this is worked so you can use it in your plugin or use custom functions plugin then paste these line of codes there. ( in custom functions plugin setting page)

Answer (score 44):

The accepted answer is very wrong. One should never be modifying the WordPress Core. Not only will edits be lost at a given update, some changes you make on a whim may compromise other functionality or even endanger the security of your site.

[Action Hooks & Filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) are included within the core to allow modifying functionality without modifying code.

An example of using the [`login_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) filter to redirect certain users can be found [here](http://tommcfarlin.com/redirect-non-admin/) and is a **much** more robust solution to your problem.

For your specific problem, you want to do this:

```
function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    return home_url('news.php');
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: The key thing that is left out of the accepted answer, and your answer is which file is supposed to editted. It's the functions.php file of the currently active theme. Right?

Comment: @ted.strauss That is the simplest place to put this logic, yes. There are a number of places it could also go, but they would generally involve creating a plugin.

Comment: +1 @ted.strauss it was't clear to me either, and for some other souls yes it works placing the code at the bottom of functions.php. Another heads up you can link directly to the permalink; return home_url('/news/');

Answer (score 19):

You can also use the customized link as:

```
https://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://example.com/news.php
```

Answer (score 13):

This may help. [Peter's Login Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/)

> Redirect users to different locations after logging in and logging out.
>
> Define a set of redirect rules for specific users, users with specific roles, users with specific capabilities, and a blanket rule for all other users. Also, set a redirect URL for post-registration. This is all managed in Settings > Login/logout redirects.
>
> You can use the syntax `[variable]username[/variable]` in your URLs so that the system will build a dynamic URL upon each login, replacing that text with the user's username. In addition to username, there is "userslug", "homeurl", "siteurl", "postid-23", "http_referer" and you can also add your own custom URL "variables"...

Comment: I will at the end of 7 days, incase someone can answer with possible changes to the functions.php, as that would be preferable compared to a 3rd party plug-in.

Answer (score 6):

```
add_action('wp_head','redirect_admin');
function redirect_admin(){
  if(is_admin()){
    wp_redirect(WP_HOME.'/news.php');
    die; // You have to die here
  }
}
```

Or if you only want to redirect other users:

```
add_action('wp_head','redirect_admin');
function redirect_admin(){
  if(is_admin()&&!current_user_can('level_10')){
    wp_redirect(WP_HOME.'/news.php');
    die; // You have to die here
  }
}
```

Comment: Would this be correct if I was wanting to only redirect subscribers?
add_action('wp_head','redirect_admin');
function redirect_admin(){
  if(current_user_can('level_0')){
    wp_redirect(WP_HOME.'/news.php');
    die;
  }
}

Answer (score 5):

If you have php 5.3+, you can use an anonymous function like so:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', function() { return site_url('news'); } );
```

Answer (score 3):

for WooCommerce: redirects for login / logout - working in 2021

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'login_redirect');

function login_redirect($redirect_to) {

    return home_url();

}

add_action('wp_logout','logout_redirect');

function logout_redirect(){

    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    
    exit;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code snippet to redirect user based on user role:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'kp_login_redirect', 10, 3 );

function kp_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $user->roles )) {
             $redirect_to = home_url("dashboard");
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

**If you are using Network site (multisite) then try this:**

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'kp_login_redirect', 10, 3 );

function kp_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $user->roles )) {
             $redirect_to = network_site_url("dashboard");
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) plugin may help - it allows you to redirect users of specific roles to specific pages.

Comment: Installed this plugin and I was no longer able to log out of my account.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is clearly not a good answer! It may solve your problem for a while, but what will happen next time you update your WordPress installation?
Your core files may get overridden and you will loose all your modifications.

As already stated by others (Dan and Travis answers), the correct answer is to use the [`login_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) filter.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this, it works for any redirection on WordPress

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect'); 

function wc_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {

   $redirect_to = 'PUT HERE URL OF THE PAGE';
   return $redirect_to;

}
```

Comment: this work with woocommerce, i just add this to de answers .......    $redirect_to =get_site_url().'/pageslug';

Answer (score 1):

```
// add the code to your theme function.php
//for logout redirection
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');
function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
wp_redirect( home_url() );
exit();
}
//for login redirection
add_action('wp_login','auto_redirect_after_login');
function auto_redirect_after_login(){
wp_redirect( home_url() );
exit();
`enter code here`}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Used theme's functions.php  
add_action('login_form', 'redirect_after_login'); 
function redirect_after_login() 
{     
global $redirect_to; 
if   (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) 
{ 
$redirect_to =   get_option('sample-page');
//  sample-page = your page name after site_url
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on some of the other answers, I came up with this:

```
/**
 * Require login on all pages
 */
function so8127453_require_login() {
  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

    $protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    $base = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $attempted_accessed_url = $protocol . $base . $uri;
    $login_url = 'https://' . $base . '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . $attempted_accessed_url;

    wp_redirect( $login_url );
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so8127453_require_login' );
```

Redirects all traffic to a login-page. And then to the attempted access URL afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching "How to Fix WordPress Login Page Refreshing and Redirecting Issue?" and did not find any good fix. From this Stackoverflow question, I have got my help. I would like to share it with others so that in case they need it, they get the help.

On my website, when I was entering email and password, I was redirecting again and again to wp-admin and asked for passwords. This code helped me to fix the issue:

```
function admin_default_page() {
  return '/';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

Right out of the box I found this which  does it for me. You can just replace the argument with a hardcoded site if you like

```
wp_loginout($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do that, will leave two options below:

1. Using [`wp_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/):

If OP knows the ID of the page, the following will do the work

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(765)) {
        wp_redirect('https://sample.com/dash'); # Using wp_redirect
        exit;
    }
}
```

2. Using [`wp_safe_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/)

This requires one to know the ID of a specific page.

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in())) {
        if (is_page(765)){ # If the user is in the page with the ID 765
            wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink('234')); # To get the URL of a specific page from the ID, and using wp_redirect
            exit; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To globally redirect after successful login, find this code in wp-login.php, under section.

```
   <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo esc_attr($redirect_to); ?>" />
```

and replace `<?php echo esc_attr($redirect_to); ?>` with your URL where you want to redirect. The URL must start with http:// and ends on /other wise page redirect to default location.

Do same thing form redirect after registration with in same file but under `<form name="registerform">` section.

Answer (score -3):

The functions.php file doesn't have anything to do with login redirect, what you should be considering it's the wp-login.php file, you can actually change the entire login interface from there, and force users to redirect to your custom pages instead of the /wp-admin/ directory.

Open the file with Notepad if using Windows or any text editor, Prese Ctrl + F (on window)
Find "wp-admin/" and change it to the folder you want it to redirect to after login, still on the same file Press Ctrl + F, find "admin_url" and the change the file name, the default file name there is "profile.php"...after just save and give a try.

```
if ( !$user->has_cap('edit_posts') && ( empty( $redirect_to ) || $redirect_to == 'wp-admin/' || $redirect_to == admin_url() ) )
        $redirect_to = admin_url('profile.php');
    wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);
    exit();
```

Or you can use the "registration-login plugin" http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/registration-login/, just simple edit the redirect urls and the links to where you want it to redirect after login, and you've got your very own custom profile.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without modifying core WP files?