# WordPress -> An e-commerce site using WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I am developing an E-commerce site in WordPress using WooCommerce plugin. By default the users are directed to myaccount page. In my website I want to redirect the users to homepage after login. How can this redirection be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect after Login on Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127453/redirect-after-login-on-wordpress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should solve your problem.You can add this code in functions.php.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'user_redirection_page');
function user_redirection_page( $redirect_to ) {
     return esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
}
```

Comment: Better use `return esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );` for minimal and reuseable code.

Comment: Yes I updated my code

Comment: This code did not work for me ,it is again directed to my account page

Comment: @Tarunya.R I tested in my site and its working for me

Comment: @Tarunya.R Are you checked my code??If your problem is solved?