# How to create custom login link and redirect in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

In Wordpress, how do I create a custom login link (not wp-login.php, I have that redirected to 'exampleDomain.com/login') where only logged out users can see the link, and after they click it and login, they are redirected to the page they were at.

I was suggested this code, but this doesn't go to a custom login link:

```
if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
{
    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', 
        wp_login_url( get_permalink() ),
        __( 'blahblahblah' )
    );
}
```

Comment: have you looked into this plugin? https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-custom-login-url-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thx for reply, I already have changed the login URL (using Ultimate Member plugin). I'm trying to just create a link that I can put in a page that goes to that custom login page, and then goes back to the existing page after the user logs in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not give a direct link to the login page?

```
<?php if( !is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
    <a href="<?= home_url('/login') ?>"><?= __('Login', 'yourthemedomain') ?></a>
<?php endif ?>
```

As for the redirect, you need to use a filter, here it is described in detail:
[Redirect after Login on Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127453/redirect-after-login-on-wordpress)