# Force a redirect after Wordpress admin login

Tags: php, wordpress

Our company uses a Wordpress plugin to view bookings. When we want to see the days bookings we have to manually switch to that page.

Is there a PHP function that forces the "after login" page to switch to the designated page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect after Login on WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127453/redirect-after-login-on-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching I found this code that's pasted into functions.php

```
function redirect_on_login() {
  return '/admin.php?page=new-page';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_on_login');
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
function admin_default_page() {
  return 'http://google.com/';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

replace the url as per your need