# how to redirect non logged users to login page and redirect to another page with saved data?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

im developing a page and using this free simple [Favorite Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/favorite-post/) plugin to add favorites to users. currently its working for logged in users only. i need to show it to non logged users and when click on its button redirect to login or register page and after logged in redirect to same page or custom page.

this is for show favorite button code on front end : or short code :[favorite-post-btn]

this is for short for code display favorited posts :[favorite-post]

if anyone can help me big it would me grateful..! thank you i will put the button code here :

```
   /**
 * Favorite post link button
 *
 * @param int $post_id
 * @return void
 */
function link_button( $post_id ) {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    $status = $this->get_post_status( $post_id, get_current_user_id() );
    ?>

    <a class="wpf-favorite-link" href="#" data-id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
        <?php if ( $status ) { ?>
            <span class="wpf-favorite">&nbsp;</span> <?php _e( 'Remove from favorite', 'wfp' ); ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <span class="wpf-not-favorite">&nbsp;</span> <?php _e( 'Add to favorite', 'wfp' ); ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </a>

    <?php
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect after Login on WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127453/redirect-after-login-on-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Checking: [Redirect after Login on WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127453/redirect-after-login-on-wordpress)

**This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380999/5214689**

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Kapsonfire. i will be follow those guide lines :)

Comment: Hello - If i'd help you please mark this answer as correct and close this topic.

Answer (score 1):

you can add some if statmen like

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])
```

or something like that, which if the condition is true makes you click the button, otherwise it redirects you to the login page

Comment: Thank you very much  Jacopo Mosconi quck reply. can you help me to fix this problem?. im new to php language