# wp_redirect() function caused endless loading/spinner on WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: redirect, woocommerce

I added wp_redirect() function for logged-in user. Because I want to show them a special page when they logged in.

```
/*
 * Logged-in user redirection for special page. 
 */
function login_redirection(){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(65309)) {
        wp_redirect('welcome-page/');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'login_redirection');
/**
 * when users logged-out, redirect them to login page
 */
add_action(
  'wp_logout',
  create_function(
    '',
    'wp_redirect(home_url("/login-page"));exit();'
  )
);
```

But this code caused endless loading/spinner on the WooCommerce Checkout page.

How can I solve this issue?
I need help with this.

Comment: You can look this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/8127629/5772301

Comment: I don't know why but the login_redirect filter is not working on my website.

Comment: If is not working than there is possibility that filter is extend. Try to increase priority of filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the solution is in front of your eyes

```
add_action(
  'wp_login',
  create_function(
    '',
    'wp_redirect(home_url("/welcome-page"));exit();'
  )
);
```