# Wordpress login to homepage not my account

Tags: wordpress

Currently, when I log in to WordPress it takes me to my account page, but instead, I'd like people who log in to be sent to the website, not their account page.  Is there a way to set this up?

Comment: The default redirect after login is the dashboard at `/wp-admin/`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect after Login on WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127453/redirect-after-login-on-wordpress)

Comment: Yes, but how do I change that to be the home page?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a wordpress developer but doing a little more looking I devised my own solution by adding the following to my functions.php file..

```
add_action('wp_login','auto_redirect_after_login');
     function auto_redirect_after_login(){
     wp_redirect( home_url() );
     exit();
}
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: I think you have copied [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48931733/1948292). Doesn't seem like your own solution.